# Rationale behind different classification of nerve fibres

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, physiology

Two main types of classification of nerve fibres are numerical and Erlanger-Gasser classification, based on diameter and conduction properties.

In numerical classification group Ia and Ib both have same conduction velocity and diameter, then on what basis are they different ,is it just because they are innervating different structures, then why this criteria is not followed further?

Also in Erlanger and Gasser classification both A and B types are myelinated and C is unmyelinated, then why is B not clubbed as subgroup of A? How is B different from A(delta) even though both are myelinated and have same conduction speed?

[image]

[image]

Source :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axon

Comment: Why downvote??? Where I am going wrong?

Comment: There are a bunch of different questions here, for one thing.

Comment: If I ask them separately then the main question can't be asked.